# OpenCV java use of the function movie()

Tags: java, function, opencv, movie

I am trying to use the function movie() in java opencv to load an avi file in my blobDetection program, but it is giving me the following error when I run my code in NetBeans:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
hypermedia.video.OpenCV.loadMovie(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
        at hypermedia.video.OpenCV.loadMovie(Native Method)
        at hypermedia.video.OpenCV.movie(OpenCV.java:991)
        at btp_test.Main.<init>(Main.java:41)
        at btp_test.Main.main(Main.java:146)
Java Result: 1
```

If anyone knows how to tackle this error, please let me know, I shall be very grateful to you, for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try JavaCV instead: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/